# Which motors are used in boston spot robot

Tags: motor, servomotor, actuator

I want to know which motors or smart servos are used in boston dynamics spot robot. Where can i read its spicification and is it possible to buy the motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Boston Dynamics' robots are hydraulic driven including this one.  I believe it is mostly composed of off-the shelf hydraulic components, but they are very expensive.

Comment: I know that most of the boston dybamics robots like bigdog and petman is using hydraulic motors. But i’m talking about their new robot mini Spot robot. It’s weight is not very large. I have seen its videos and read about it, and i found that it donot uses hydraulics at all. It uses electrical motors. My question was only which electrical motors, that provides this much torqe and speed. Their is possiblity that they are using their own motors but i want to know.

Answer (score 2):

I had the chance to play with Spot this afternoon and it is not hydraulic.

I bet for a stepper motor with cycloidal gears and position encoders. But I not really sure which kind of motor. They didn't want me to tear it down...

[image]

Comment: if anything it's a BLDC motor, why use heavy, space wasteful steppers?

Comment: Hard to say. steppers are very cheap to manufacture, they have huge reluctant torque (cogging) that can be compensated. Adding a digital encoder to a stepper could be a good solution. But I am not sure whether or not I am right.